# Requesting email with Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, email

I am trying to request the email from a user using the twitter login and it always return me the following error

```
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException: Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.
```

I've followed all the steps to develop this email request in the fabric's page. I've requested the access to twitter and they have answered me with a confirmation email and I've configured all the necessary items in my twitter app management control panel, but the email request always send me to the failure method and throw that exception.

any idea?

```
private void twitterConfig() {
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =
            new TwitterAuthConfig("Consumer Key (API Key)",
                    "Consumer Secret (API Secret");

    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
            authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<String> result) {
                    System.out.println();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    notificationManager.showMessage(getString(R.string.error_cant_get_login));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            notificationManager.showMessage(getString(R.string.error_generic));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Munon you have resolve this problem? i am facing this issue.. plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated at the bottom of the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/request-user-email-address.html):

> Even if the user grants access to her email address, it is not
>   guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone
>   signed up for Twitter with a phone number instead of an email address,
>   the email field may be empty. When this happens, the failure method
>   will be called because there is no email address available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read this statement but i'm trying with my twitter user and i've a valid email address, so that's not the problem

Comment: same problem. Not giving email even if registered via email.

Comment: No @RahulRastogi, I've lost the faith in Twitter login, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I Yes It's true. You need to change permission settings from permission tab inside your selected application.

https://apps.twitter.com/app/PROJECT_ID/permissions

[image]**Additional Permissions**

> These additional permissions require that you provide URLs to your
>   application or service's privacy policy and terms of service. You can
>   configure these fields in your Application Settings.
>       Request email addresses from users

That will enable after few hrs/min once you do change.

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback < String > () {
 @Override
 public void success(Result < String > result) {
  // Do something with the result, which provides the email address

  Log.v("log_tag", "success email true > " + result.data);
 }

 @Override
 public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
  // Do something on failure
  Log.v("log_tag", "success email false > " + exception);

 }
});
```

[As neeeko said](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html) It's not guaranteed you will get an email address.

Thanks

Comment: I have followed same and login with email but still not getting email id from twitter

Comment: have you request for email from app settings ?